# Spring project obfuscation using proguard using Maven

Tags: spring, maven, proguard

is there any good example for obfuscating Spring application using proguard & Maven ?  I tried adding this snippet in pom.xml. My project is compiling and running, but did not get obfuscated. 
I was able to decompile my war file and view the code. Is there any setting required to obfuscate generated file ??

```
            <!-- ProGuard obfuscation plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
                <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <configuration>
                            <obfuscate>true</obfuscate>
                            <proguardVersion>5.2.1</proguardVersion>
                            <options>
                                <option>-target 1.7</option>
                                <option>-dontnote</option>
                                <option>-dontpreverify</option>
                                <option>-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses</option>
                                <option>-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers</option>
                                <option>-allowaccessmodification</option>
                                <option>-repackageclasses ''</option>
                                <option>-keep public class ${mainClass} { public static void
                                    main(java.lang.String[]); }</option>
                                <option>-keepattributes
                                    InnerClasses,Signature,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod</option>
                                <option>-keepclassmembers enum * { public static **[] values();
                                    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String); }</option>
                                <option>-dontwarn org.spout.**</option>
                                <option>-dontwarn com.google.**</option>
                            </options>

                            <proguardInclude>${basedir}/proguard.conf</proguardInclude>
                            <includeDependency>false</includeDependency>
                            <libs>
                                <lib>${java.home}/lib/jce.jar</lib>
                                <lib>${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</lib>
                                <lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib>
                            </libs>
                        </configuration>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>proguard</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>


                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
                        <artifactId>proguard-base</artifactId>
                        <version>5.2.1</version>
                        <scope>runtime</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
                        <artifactId>proguard</artifactId>
                        <version>4.4</version>
                    </dependency>


                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```